# llvm opt -O3 fail (?)

Tags: optimization, llvm, static-analysis

I need to **identify integer variables which behave like boolean variables**, that is, they can only have the values `0` or `1`.
For that purpose, I modified the llvm bitcode to add an equivalent instruction to:

```
int tmp = someVar*(someVar-1);
```

Hoping that agressive `O3` optimizations will identify `tmp` as being the constant value `0`. Here is a `C` version of the code I used:

```
int should_expand(char *s)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char *p = s;

    if (p && *p == '&')
    {
        ret = 1;
    }
    tmp = ret * (ret - 1);
    return tmp;
}
```

When I examine the `*.ll` file I see that almighty clang 6.0.0 failed
to realize `tmp` is actually `0`:

```
define i32 @should_expand(i8* readonly %s) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %tobool = icmp eq i8* %s, null
  br i1 %tobool, label %if.end, label %land.lhs.true

land.lhs.true:                                    ; preds = %entry
  %tmp = load i8, i8* %s, align 1, !tbaa !2
  %cmp = icmp eq i8 %tmp, 38
  %spec.select = zext i1 %cmp to i32
  br label %if.end

if.end:                                           ; preds = %land.lhs.true, %entry
  %ret.0 = phi i32 [ 0, %entry ], [ %spec.select, %land.lhs.true ]
  %sub = add nsw i32 %ret.0, -1
  %tmp1 = sub nsw i32 0, %ret.0
  %mul = and i32 %sub, %tmp1
  ret i32 %mul
}
```

Does that make sense? are there any external static analyzers I can use, that inter-operate smoothly with clang? or any other trick I can use?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be easy enough to write a function pass that looks for constants, icmps, fcmps and selects, extends the set recursively by looking at users of the values in the set, and then applies brute force and the constant folder to look for instructions that evaluate to the same result independent of the input values. But it would, perhaps, spend a lot of CPU at compile time for very rare gains. The passes included in LLVM generally try to be either very cheap or very beneficial, which is probably why noone has included a pass like this.

Comment: As a side note, gcc [optimizes this correctly](https://godbolt.org/z/7FtAcn).