# Using Clang Static Analyzer directly on bitcode files

Tags: c, llvm, bitcode, clang-static-analyzer

I wanted to know **if clang analyzer can be made to work directly on bitcode (`*.bc`) files?** Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533500/llvm-opt-o3-fail) about identification of integer variables that can only have the values `0` or `1`, I've started exploring the clang analyzer, and it gave me good results.
For example, when I used the following `C` code with:

```
$ scan-build clang -O3 ./main.c
```

it found out that **division by zero is indeed not feasible**:

```
int should_expand(char *s)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char *p;

    for (p = s; p && *p; p++)
    {
        if (*p == '\\')     { p++;     }
        else if (*p == '&') { ret = 1; }
    }
    if (!((0 <= ret) && (ret <= 1)))
    {
        int j = 0;
        ret = 5 / j;
    }
    return ret;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (should_expand(argv[1]))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I thought I'd insert an `if (!((0 <= _) && (_ <= 1)))` statement
for every integer variable, and then feed the resulting bitcode files
to clang analyzer. Problem is, I can't seem to find if it can handle
bitcode files or just c source files? any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang static analyzer works on clang AST. It cannot use bitcode as input – it's low-level for the analyzer.